# data size blows out when storing in bcolz

Tags: python, blaze, bcolz

I have a dataset with ~7M rows and 3 columns, 2 numeric and 1 consisting of ~20M distinct string uuids. The data takes around 3G as a csv file and castra can store it in about 2G.
I would like to test out bcolz with this data.

I tried

```
odo(dask.dataframe.from_castra('data.castra'), 'data.bcolz')
```

which generated ~70G of data before exhausting inodes on the disk
and crashing.

What is the recommended way to get such a dataset into bcolz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Killian Mie on the [bcolz mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bcolz/Slmy3yMk9Rc/UFN-TMmpBgAJ):

Read csv in chunks via `pandas.read_csv()`, convert your string column from Python object dtype to a fix length numpy dtype, say, 'S20', then append as numpy array to ctable.

Also, set `chunklen=1000000` (or similar) at ctable creation which will avoid creating hundreds of files under the /data folder (probably not optimal for compression though)

The 2 steps above worked well for me (20 million rows, 40-60 columns).

Try this:

```
df0 = ddf.from_castra("data.castra")
df = odo.odo(df0, pd.DataFrame)
names = df.columns.tolist()
types = ['float32', 'float32', 'S20']  # adjust 'S20' to your max string length needs
cols = [bcolz.carray(df[c].values, dtype=dt) for c, dt in zip(names, types)]

ct = bcolz.zeros(0, dtype=np.dtype(zip(names, types)), 
                    mode='w', chunklen=1000000, 
                    rootdir="data.bcolz")
ct.append(cols)
```